# how to retrieve values of variables in the optimised objective function using Lpsolve in R

Tags: r, linear-programming, lpsolve

Im trying to find the values of x and y at the optimized objective function.
This is the code for finding the optimum that i used

```
objective.in=c(6.55,7.9)
const.mat=matrix(c(0.25,0,0.25,0.5,0.5,0.5),nrow=3,byrow = TRUE)
const.dir<-c("<=","<=","<=")
const.rhs<-c(500,200,200)
lp("max",objective.in,const.mat,const.dir,const.rhs)
```

[image]

Comment: On the last line, assign it into an object, then use `str()` to see how that object is structured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
> library(lpSolve)
> objective.in=c(6.55,7.9)
> const.mat=matrix(c(0.25,0,0.25,0.5,0.5,0.5),nrow=3,byrow = TRUE)
> const.dir<-c("<=","<=","<=")
> const.rhs<-c(500,200,200)
> res<-lp("max",objective.in,const.mat,const.dir,const.rhs)
> res$objval
[1] 3160
```

Use `?lp.object` to find more information about what is available in the object that `lp()` returns.